# How to load data of different models

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

Please bear with me, I am new to MVC

using EF I created two tables Customer & Order they have foreign key constraint on customer ID.

I created a controller (name HomeController) & provided the link to navigate to AddCustomer & AddOrder Views.

AddCustomer view adds a new customer, I am passing the Customer model to this view. This works fine for me.

In the AddOrder view, I am passing the Order model. It has some textboxes, also a drop down to display the list of customer to select from. My problem is how to populate the list of customers in  AddOrder view?? The model of AddOrder is Order, how I would fetch the list of customer in it?

Comment: You should have to do some research initially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use ViewBag to populate your dropdown.

Controller

```
 ViewBag.Customer = new SelectList(db.Customer, "Name", "Name");//Name or id as per your requirements
```

View

```
@Html.DropDownList("Customer", String.Empty)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a list of Customers as a property in Orders model.

```
public string list<string> CustomerNames { get; set;}
```